# How to bind 'this' to an object arrow function?

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

Let us suppose we have an object `profile` with properties `name` and `getName` method (arrow function).

```
profile = {
    name: 'abcd',
    getName: () => {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

I want to call `getName` method by keeping the arrow function intact, and **not** changing it to regular function.

How can I get the output `abcd` by calling `getName()`.

You can add expressions inside `getName`.

Will `call()` or `bind()` help? If so, how?

**DO NOT CHANGE THE ARROW FUNCTION TO REGULAR FUNCTION**

*-- EDITED --*

I just want to ask how can we use arrow functions inside objects so that it reflect the results as we will get in regular functions.

It was just an interview question.

Comment: *Will call() or bind() help?* Arrow functions do not have context to override, so you cannot use `.bind` or `.call`

Comment: as a side note : javascript has [`getters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: `this` inside arrow functions is *explicitly literal*. That's one of their distinguishing features. It's explicitly impossible to change their `this` binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: Why are you so adamant about using an arrow function when it's exactly the thing causing a problem?

Comment: @deceze this is not for use, it was asked by an interviewer.

Answer (score 8):

Without changing it to a regular function, the only way to get to the `name` property from the inner function is through accessing the outer *variable name*, which is `profile`:

```js
const profile = {
    name: 'abcd',
    getName: () => {
        console.log(profile.name);
    }
}

profile.getName();
```

Comment: I guess we should close it as dupe. Though not exact dupe, linked post surely solves the problem.

Comment: @Rajesh That "dupe" is rather different.

Comment: @deceze OP is focused on using arrow function but inherently, what we are trying to achieve is to have a self reference in a method. Following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206385/3783478) has very similar approach. Hence, I marked it as dupe. If i have misunderstood the question, apologies!